# React state not updating after delete request

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have a logout button in my navbar that deletes the current session on my backend(rails) and then sets my user state to null. The delete request works fine but when I set my user state to null it doesn't show until I refresh the page.

this is my initial fetch request to obtain my user:

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [runs, setRuns] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/me').then((r) => {
      if (r.ok) {
        r.json().then((user) => setUser(user));
      }
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/runs')
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then(setRuns);
  }, []); 


  return (
    <div className="App">

      { !user ? null : <NavBar setUser={ setUser }  /> }

      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Welcome setUser = {setUser} />} />
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home user={user} />} />
        <Route path='/login' element= {<Login setUser = {setUser} />} />
        <Route path='/signup' element= {<Signup setUser = {setUser} />} />

      </Routes>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is my navbar:

```
function NavBar( {setUser} ) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleLogoutClick() {
    fetch('/logout', { method: 'DELETE' }).then((r) => {
      if (r.ok) {
        setUser(null);
      }
    }).then(navigate('/'))
  }

  return (
    <div>

      <IconButton onClick={handleLogoutClick} icon={<GrLogout />}/>
   

    </div>
  )
}
```

I want my navbar to disappear if the user is null, but when I logout and get redirected to my homepage I can still see my navbar, its not until I refresh that my navbar disappears.

Comment: `function NavBar( setUser ) {` isn't right, the argument is the entire props object - if you want to extract the function immediately, destructure it

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry about that, typo on my end but yes they are in curly brackets in my code